# Missing Setup->VLAN on DD-WRT Web GUI?

Tags: dd-wrt, vlan, buffalo-router

Please note that I've already posted this question on the dd-wrt forums.

I am using "DD-WRT v24-sp2 (08/07/10) std" on a WZR-HP-G300NH model Buffalo router.

I've found a number of tutorials online that talk about using Setup->VLAN on the menu system of the GUI interface to configure VLANs, but on my own router, it appears that VLAN configuration is located elsewhere; mainly in the Setup->Networking->VLAN Tagging section of the GUI.

[image]

I would gladly just use the bash shell to configure the vlans on the router, but every tutorial I read refers to "changing the gui to reflect the changes made in the bash prompt". 
Are there any tutorials or documentation that you are aware of that that refer to the Setup->Networking->VLAN Tagging GUI portion of my router?

Answer (score 1):

I switched to OpenWRT. Instead of DD-WRT

Comment: Can you explain what it is about OpenWRT that resolves the question?